# Bootstrap grid system- Can we use 2 col-*-12 in a .row class?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

From all the links I have read online, I understand that the sum of all the col classes inside a row class should be 12.

But, I have seen cases where people are using multiple col-*-12 inside a row. Is this a valid bootstrap syntax?

For example- The following is VALID-

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
  </div>
</div>
```

And the following is also VALID

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-9">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Is the following VALID?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
```

Please give proper reasoning.

**EDIT:**
Thanks for letting me know that it's VALID. Can anyone let me know if it's a good idea to do so?
or may be, doing the following is better

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
```

Which one is better out of the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is valid. According to the [doc](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

> If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line.

UPDATE:

If you have different height blocks and you put everything inside one row block, you will get incorrect behavior. See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/H93vNpbUem5XBMYiCjec?p=preview)

but if you use `col-X-12` only, it does not really matter the way you use `row` classes. I think for `col-X-12` you can even skip `row` and `col-X-12` class. Just put everything inside regular `div` tag and you will get 100% width.

Comment: @yuyokk- I have done an EDIT in the question. Can you please answer that as well?

Comment: If you have different height blocks and you put everything inside one row block, you will get incorrect behavior. See this http://plnkr.co/edit/H93vNpbUem5XBMYiCjec?p=preview

Comment: but if you use col-X-12 only, it does not really matter the way you use row classes. I think for col-X-12 you can even skip row and col-X-12 class. Just put everything inside regular <div> tag and you will get 100% width.

Comment: Can you please add that to your answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: it does not let me paste plunker link in the body :(

Comment: I have made that plunker link work :)

Comment: I don't really see the plnkr as "incorrect behavior". It's simply floating the wrapping columns which in some cases is desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is valid, it just defines two `100% width div` elements, that are both in one row.

It has no real difference, if you use it like that or put them separately in two `row` divs, of course depending on your css that you apply to the row.

In your example, the `col-xs-12` and `col-md-12` will be stacked on each other, with both having 100% width. There is even no real difference that you defined `xs` and `md`, because they will always be 100% in width, on all screen widths.

Comment: @brance- I have done an EDIT in the question. Though your answer partially answers that, would you like to add anything to it?

Comment: What about, say, 4 `col-*-6`s?